# How do I configure PHP 5.5 opcache so I can run the same script in different environments?

Tags: php, nginx, opcache

I have a server setup running Nginx 1.1.19 and PHP 5.5.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When opcache is enabled, if there is a file that is identical in both my `development` and `production` environments, that file will always be run from `production`. However, if I change just one character in either file, PHP will correctly run the proper script.

For example, if I clone the same project to two different directories and the only thing that I change between the two is the `APP_ENV` environmental variable in the configuration file, whenever I point my browser to the `development` environment, all of the database parameters from the `production` config are loaded.

If I turn `opcache` off, the weird behavior ceases and everything works as I expect.

Is there an `opcache` config parameter that I can set that will force PHP to resolve the correct script location? I tried setting `revalidate_path` to `1`, but that just switched the problem around (pointing to either `production` or `development` always yielded the `development` environment.

For now I've just turned `opcache` off, but I'd like to know more about it.

Comment: If you're running production and development from the same pool (which seems like a bad idea to me), and the file in both environments is exactly the same, I don't see how opcache would know to distinguish the two.  Wouldn't it make more sense to have different pools?

Comment: Thanks @DanFarrell, I hadn't thought of that. Come to think of it, that's how I have all of my boxes that are being monitored by New Relic setup (one pool per Vhost). BTW, It's called "production" but this isn't really a live app. I wouldn't put a dev env on a production box. I'm just playing around with Vagrant.

Comment: Opcache always fully resolves the filename of any files that it caches, hence two separate app references would only access the same compiled script if the filenames resolve to the same file.  So I am a bit confused by your description.  Can you give a bit more details / specific examples of where this occurs?

Comment: the problem also occures if you are using php-fpm with chroot option specified. that way you have good chances to find a /htdocs/index.php in mutliple vhosts - same filename and full path, same file checksum, still different enviroments.

Comment: You can get past the chroot option that bhelm is correctly identifying by using the `opcache.use_cwd` i describe in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: YES - taken from an [answer over on ServerFault I provided to a similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/548837/creating-multiple-users-on-single-php-fpm-pool/705878#705878):

> Make sure that `opcache.use_cwd` parameter is set to `true` for your application's configuration of OpCache - it's set to `false` by default and leaving it set to default will probably cause collisions if you're hosting more than one PHP application on your system...

When originally shipped, `opcache.us_cwd` was set to a default of `false` - that's how I get it on an Ubuntu 14.04 Zend Server AMI from Zend themselves, though I have heard that some modern distributions have changed the default setting from false to true.  I haven't personally seen any but it's worth confirming yourself on your setup to validate if [TerryE'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142045/terrye)s comment is accurate for your specific configuration on your webhost.

Comment: The original post is referencing apache, but this directive should function similarly for nginx.